# routeprovider resolve not restricting access with parse.com

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, roles, route-provider

I want to restrict page to only Administrators. I am finding that my auth factory is not completing before resolve returns answer to route. When i follow/watch the code path page gets loaded before the factory finishes.
I am thinking i need to do better with promises and /or  ".then()".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

My route code:

```
.when("/admin", {
    templateUrl : "templates/admin.htm",
    controller: 'AdminCtrl',
    resolve : {
            'auth' : function(AuthService){
                return AuthService.isAdmin();
            }
    }
}).run(function($rootScope, $location){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection){
        if(rejection === 'Not Administrator'){
            $location.path('/404');
        }
        if(rejection === 'Not Authenticated'){
            $location.path('/404');
        }
    });
});
```

My factory:

```
    app.factory('AuthService', function($q){
    var isAuthenticated = Parse.User.current();
    var isAdmin = undefined;
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        return {
            authenticate : function(){
                if(isAuthenticated){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return $q.reject('Not Authenticated');
                }
            },
            isAdmin : function(){
                if(isAuthenticated){
                    userHasRole(currentUser, "Administrator").then(function(isRole) {
                        console.log((isRole)? "user is admin" : "user is not admin");
                        isAdmin = isRole;
                        return isAdmin;
                    }).then(function(isAdmin){
                        if(isAdmin){
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject('Not Administrator');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return $q.reject('Not Authenticated');
                }
            }
        };
});  

function userHasRole(user, roleName) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.equalTo("name", roleName);
    query.equalTo("users", user);
    return query.find().then(function(roles) {
        if(roles.length > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I thought maybe my security roles may have cause this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So close.

`isAdmin` is returning undefined because you're missing the return statement before `userHasRole`, so you're calling it, but then `isAdmin` hits the end of the `if( isAuthenticated )` block without a return value since it doesn't know it's supposed to return the result of `userHasRole`.

Comment: do you mean i need   <code>if(isAuthenticated){ return { userHasRole......}  }else{.....<code>  ?  this gives me lint error unexpected token??

Comment: You wouldn't wrap it in `{ }`s, just `return userHasRole...`  That function gets fired of asynchronously while the main thread continues on, since the main thread doesn't know that it's supposed to wait for the return value.